# What does "pruning code" mean in the context of java language?

Tags: java

While reading a book called Java Perfomance, I came across that term.
You can find it here [free sample pages](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449358457_sampler.pdf) on page 6 "Write less code"

Comment: What does "pruning" mean, and what does "code" mean?

Comment: code means program code, pruning means pruning. I'm not a native speaker so it's hard to understand such terms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pruning), the word pruning is defined as

"to cut or lop superfluous or undesired twigs, branches, or roots from; trim."

In the context of code, pruning is the activity of removing unnecessary and unreachable code so as to make the code more readable and easily maintainable.

For example, consider the following code

```
int i;
i = 1;
... <some more code>
```

can be shortened to

```
int i = 1;
... <some more code>
```

The benefits seem marginal in this case, but if you prune your code on a regular basis, the benefits add up to be significant.

Comment: This also accounts for several statements of variable initialization where you can put everything in one line. Example: `func1(func2(func3(), func4()))` - Does look good on one line and messy if split up on multiple lines, of course only if it's not too long.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with definition given in the accepted answer, I don't think the example given (or the one in the comments) are correct. Strictly, these are just "refactoring" rather than "pruning" because the code that is changed is live, not dead (unreachable). "Pruning" is more specific than simply a refactoring which reduces codebase size.

This would be an example in Java. Since the statement `return "Condition other";` cannot be reached and is therefore dead code, deleting it would be pruning.

```
    if (myCondition) {
        return "Condition yes";
    }
    if (!myCondition) {
        return "Condiiton no";
    }
    return "Condition other";
```

Comment: In this case this would lead to `return myCondition ? "Condition yes" : "Condiiton no";`